# Does AWS Cognito have a REST endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I got lost in all of the documentation for AWS Cognito, I was used to working with Firebase Auth/Auth0 and similar Auth as a service solution and usually I get an HTTP endpoint that I can use to authenticate.

With AWS Cognito it seems like the only way to implement authentication is by using their "Hosted UI", which (I'm sorry to say) is not that good.

I would like my users to use my UI that was built with JS. I noticed that I can use Amplify to some extent for more customization, but the library is too big for me (and probably for most cases); it's 700K, that's too much for today's standards.

I crawled the docs and, to be honest, I found them to be confusing and a little bit claustrophobic (lots of repeating documents). I'm not trying to bash Amazon, I'm just genuinely asking: did I miss something? Is there a REST API that I can use, or any other solution that won't require me to use their huge JS library and still stay serverless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AWS Cognito SDK to implement your own custom library and code for authentication.

Check the [AWS SDK Example with Javascript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html).

Note: The SDKs internally uses the AWS REST API and if you need you can implement using the REST API also.

However, the simplest approach would be to use AWS AmplifyJS but as you mentioned the file size is bit large since it also comes with more functionalities.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but your link is about IAM authentication with DB instances.
Are you sure this is relevant?